# How can i remove dark spots from skin?

Tags: personal-care

I had acne on my skin.Anyone tell me how to  remove acne spots from my skin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few skincare options you can try. A combination of brightening ingredients (such as Vitamin C) and chemical exfoliations (AHA and BHA) will help. These are available in toners, serums, lotions, and oils. You can also try retinol ingredients (which are now available over the counter). These ingredients are often found in combination products - many options are available in high-end make-up stores as well as in big box stores.

Be sure to wear sunscreen every day while using these! Most will make your skin more sensitive to sun damage, so if you are not already applying daily sunscreen it is essential to add that to your routine.

Finally, you can consider seeing a dermatologist for a specialized treatment such as microdermabrasion or prescription skincare products.